Verbs for to punish
Is there any difference in meaning or in the nuance of usage between the verbs strafen and bestrafen or are they simply synonyms ?

The verb strafen is seldom used. You can find it in frozen expressions as

Das Ergebnis strafte ihn Lügen.
The result gave the lie to him.


Sie ist damit genug gestraft.
She's cursed with that.

Always use bestrafen otherwise.


Is there any difference in meaning or in the nuance of usage between the verbs strafen and bestrafen

Yes, there is and it is a real subtle difference. You have perhaps noticed that you can use the two words interchangeably on most occasions. The problem is aggravated by the fact that English doesn't differentiate between the two and the translation for both is "to punish".

strafen means "to punish" and describes the act itself. There is also a related noun ("Strafe"), meaning "punishment". Both these words are without connotations.

bestrafen, on the other hand, is administering or handing out a punishment onto some recipient. The correlated noun "Bestrafung" also exists.


Here is an example hopefully showing the difference, although this difference shows better in the nouns than in the verbs: the "Strafe" is what a judge will hand out, say, "one year in jail". The "Bestrafung" is the act of putting the person into jail and keeping him there for a year.

Hard disagree on "strafen" and "bestrafen" being roughly the same. See Janka's answer, "strafen" is very rarely used (at least for Standard German German). Your example using "Strafe" and "Bestrafung" is not an example, because those are nouns, not the verbs the question is about.

@Raketenolli: I wrote that I use nouns because the difference shows better in the nouns - and you promptly noticed that I used indeed nouns! Many, many thanks for pointing out to me that verbs are not nouns, I wouldn't have known otherwise. By the way: between "roughly the same" (what you wrote) and "a real subtle difference" (what I wrote) is a subtle difference - and if you are "gestraft" with the inability of noticing that, you are indeed "bestraft" enough, so that I will not point out that these words can be used interchangeably on some occasions.

Um das nochmal ganz deutlich zu machen: "strafen" wird im Hochdeutschen (in Deutschland) so gut wie gar nicht verwendet (siehe Jankas Antwort), und "you can use the two words interchangeably" trifft m. E. nicht zu. Der Unterschied - oder die Abwesenheit desselben -, den Du mit "Strafe" und "Bestrafung" (beides gängige Wörter im Hochdeutschen) versuchst zu erklären, besteht eben nur zwischen den beiden Nomen, und nicht zwischen den beiden Verben. Daher ist dieses Beispiel kein geeignetes Beispiel.
